# Expose multiple different objects on the window with webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a module which needs to expose a number of different classes to the user. Lets say ClassA and ClassB:

```
export class ClassA {}
export class ClassB {}
```

However, when used in HTML without a bundler (e.g. with `libraryTarget: 'window'` in webpack), I need these two classes to be exposed as root level objects:

```
window.ClassA = ClassA;
window.ClassB = ClassB;
```

This is because the user needs to be able to do things like:

```
var a = new ClassA(new ClassB(), new ClassB())
```

However, webpack will only let me assign the exports to the `window` inside a singular namespace. With `library: MyLib` in webpack, and code that uses my library has to use this namespace:

```
var a = new MyLib.ClassA(new MyLib.ClassB(), new MyLib.ClassB())
```

This isn't what I want. Is there a way to make these classes available on the window object directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this section](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-via-object-assignment) of the doc, what you want to achieve is doable by ensuring:

1. You module is the entry point
2. `output.library` is falsy
3. `output.libraryTarget = "window"`

Comment: Yep, that seems to have worked. I just missed this in the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have multiple entry points (one for each object),
then try something like:

```js
output: {
    library: [
        'MyBundle',
        '[name]'
    ],
    libraryTarget: 'var'
}
```

How I use it:

```
var myObject = new MyBundle['/app/home-page'].default;
```

> **Note** that the path to `home-page.js` entry-file is actually "`./src/app/home-page.js`", but seems WebPack removes root-dir prefix, and `.js` suffix of course.
>
> I mean, check with "`console.log(MyBundle);`" what `key` works for you.